# Website is loading shifted to the right, only on iOS

Tags: html, ios, safari, viewport

Anytime I visit my website on an iOS mobile device, it loads the page, but everything is shifted about 100pixels to the right. This happens in Chrome and Safari

This doesn't happen on desktop or any Android device I've tested.

Here is a link to the site so you can see for yourself: [Flitti](http://flitti.com)

Does anybody know why this is happening? Or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**
I was using the following CSS on the page-container

```
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

I forgot to add the vendor prefixes. It should be:

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

[Research - Which vendor prefixes are needed?](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/which-vendor-prefixes-are-needed/)

Answer (score 1):

Really basic, but do you have the site's body set for centering in the mobile media query?

eg:

```
body{
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

and if you do, do you have anything that is canceling that code out?

EDIT:
Additionally, do you have the appropriate webkits to support the browsers?

```
-webkit-
-moz-
-o-
```